# Backbone.js : Associating params to events callback function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, backbone-events

I am creating custom events for a list of events. I have these events in a file (event.js) like this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports =  {

    'event1': ['test1','data1'],
    'event2': ['test2','data2']
  };
});
```

I am creating event trigger for each of these events:

```
createTriggers: function(Events){ //Events = require(event.js);
      _.defer(function(){
        _.each(Events,function(data,event){
           var events = function () { console.log("Data is "+this.data)};
           events = _.bind(events,data); 
           targ.events.bind(event,events); //targ is the Backbone event object
        });
      });
  }
```

But when I trigger any of the event:

```
  this.trigger("event1");
```

I get output as Data is undefined. Why the values '['test1','data1']' is not fetched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering these 2 lines:

```
var events = function () { console.log("Data is "+this.data)};
events = _.bind(events,data);
```

Assuming that `data` at this point is an Array (`['test1','data1']`), your code does this:

```js
console.log("Data is " + ['test1','data1'].data);
```

You probably want:

```
var events = function () { console.log("Data is "+this)};
events = _.bind(events,data);
```

or

```
var events = function () { console.log("Data is "+this.data)};
events = _.bind(events,{data: data});
```

see Underscore bind [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) for more examples.